# Adding background image from long url in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to try add background image through url But image is not showing.
Here what am I using.

```html
    <div style="background-image:url(https://i.amz.mshcdn.com/pr8NZRyZf0Kmz4FSGMkLtxUwZ70=/575x323/filters:quality(90)/https%3A%2F%2Fblueprint-api-production.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fuploads%2Fstory%2Fthumbnail%2F65469%2F23ede933-7d84-40fb-a9ee-eb7787a3feac.jpg);">content goes here...</div>
```

I checked url is working if you copy and past url in browser you will see image. Then why it's not showing in background. One of my wordpress site automatically fetch url for background image. Please let me know how can I solve this.

Comment: try to put the url inside single quotes url('urlLink.jpg')

Comment: can you give me screenshot or site url where you want to use this background.

Comment: Here is site url http://world.octabyte.org/  images are not displaying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add quotes. In most of the cases it's not mandatory but in your case, it's needed as you have some special characters that can create confusion.

For example, You have a closing `)` inside the URL which made it to be closed before the end.

```html
<div style="background-image:url('https://i.amz.mshcdn.com/pr8NZRyZf0Kmz4FSGMkLtxUwZ70=/575x323/filters:quality(90)/https%3A%2F%2Fblueprint-api-production.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fuploads%2Fstory%2Fthumbnail%2F65469%2F23ede933-7d84-40fb-a9ee-eb7787a3feac.jpg');height:200px;">content goes here...</div>
```

**UPDATE**

As you are not able to add quotes in the URL (because it's generated automatically with wordpress). Here is a jQuery solution that will add the quotes for you. (but you need to be able to target only this div).

```js
//change the selector to get only the needed DIV
var sel = $('div')

var url = sel.attr('style');
url = url.replace("url(","url('"); //add the first quote
url = url.replace("jpg)","jpg')"); //add the last quote

sel.attr('style',url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-image:url(https://i.amz.mshcdn.com/pr8NZRyZf0Kmz4FSGMkLtxUwZ70=/575x323/filters:quality(90)/https%3A%2F%2Fblueprint-api-production.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fuploads%2Fstory%2Fthumbnail%2F65469%2F23ede933-7d84-40fb-a9ee-eb7787a3feac.jpg);height:200px;">content goes here...</div>
```

*This method is not generic and will only work in this case, so you may update the code in other situation*

Comment: But actually as I said it's wordpress site and plugin automatically set background image for this. How can I solve this there

Comment: @ArfanHaider save your image directly into your wordpress site and use it, i think it would be better

Comment: is it possible to remove this issue via javascript ?

Comment: @ArfanHaider yes sure ;) one sec, will create a working snippet for this

Comment: @ArfanHaider check again, i added a JS way yo add quotes

Answer (score 3):

See the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri):

> Some characters appearing in an unquoted URI, such as parentheses, white space characters, single quotes (') and double quotes ("), must be escaped with a backslash so that the resulting URI value is a URI token: '(', ')'.

Either:

- escape those characters
- use a quoted `url()` (example below)
- use URLs without those characters in

```html
    <div style="background-image:url('https://i.amz.mshcdn.com/pr8NZRyZf0Kmz4FSGMkLtxUwZ70=/575x323/filters:quality(90)/https%3A%2F%2Fblueprint-api-production.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fuploads%2Fstory%2Fthumbnail%2F65469%2F23ede933-7d84-40fb-a9ee-eb7787a3feac.jpg');">content goes here...</div>
```